# Using dense rank after sorting the records

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I need some help in using the dense rank function in sql

I have the following data in the table,

[image]

I want to sort the records based on the CREATED DATE column and then assign the same row number
if the document id is the same for multiple records. I have used the below query but the row number is not sorted

```
 SELECT * FROM (((SELECT * FROM (SELECT   DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_ID) AS "RowNumber",
VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_ID,VC_VIN_LOCALE,VC_VIN_IMDOC_CREATE_DATE,VC_VIN_CARLINE_CODE,VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_TYPE
from (SELECT DISTINCT VC_VIN_IMDOC_CREATE_DATE,VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_TYPE, VC_VIN_LOCALE,VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_ID,VC_VIN_CARLINE_CODE from OK_DC.GMS3_VC_MME_VIN_SI_DETAIL ORDER BY VC_VIN_IMDOC_CREATE_DATE DESC)))))  ;
```

I want to achieve something like below.

[image]

Could someone please help me with the query.

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> Oracle.  Which one is this?

Comment: @Eric, sorry it is Sql.

Comment: `SQL` is just a languange.  Which dbms?  Oracle?  Sql Server?  MySQL? Postgres?

Comment: @Eric I am using Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps.  First is to get the created date.  Then assign the row number:

```
select vsd.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by max_cd desc, VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_ID) as rowNumber
from (select vsd.*,
             MAX(vsd.VC_VIN_IMDOC_CREATE_DATE) over (partition by vscd.VC_VIN_DOCUMENT_ID) as max_cd
      from OK_DC.GMS3_VC_MME_VIN_SI_DETAIL vsd
     ) vsd;
```

Comment: Hi Gordan
Thank you so much. Exactly what I need. Really appreciate your help.